# One-To-Many-Relationship: How to sort data based on latest payments and based on their latest order ids

Tags: php, laravel, one-to-many, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

I have an Online Store project written in Laravel 5.8 and I can properly get the latest orders like this:

```
$orders = Order::query()->latest('orders.created_at');
```

And at the Blade:

```
@forelse($orders as $order)
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr>
@empty
@endforelse
```

But now I need to sort data based on the latest payments.

I have also define One To Many relationship between these two Models:

**Payment.php**:

```
public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class, 'pay_ord_id', 'pay_id');
    }
```

**Order.php**:

```
public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class, 'pay_ord_id', 'ord_id');
    }
```

Basically every payment has a record named `pay_ord_id` which is the Order Id.

And I need to sort data with these conditions:

> 1- Get **latest** orders
>
> 2- Go to the `payments` table and search data with the **retrieved order ids**
>
> 3- Sort data based on **latest** `payments` data

So how can I properly get the latest payments based on the latest order ids in this situation?

---

**UPDATE:**

```
$orders = Order::query()->latest('orders.created_at')->with([
            'payments' => function($query){
                $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
            }
        ])->get();
```

I just tried this but still shows latest orders!

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: no you did not try my answer. please check again. zemnan order and sefaresh are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

forgive me that I don't know Laravelle but the software principles are the same everywhere. Wouldn't you be better getting the correct order in the query in the first place. I saw on [this page](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) that (like most other DB frameworks) Laravelle supports an 'order by' as part of the query.?

Comment: Yes but I wanted to do this with Eloquent relationships

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `with()` function to get all order payments

```
$orders = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->with([
    'payments' => function($query){
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: missing `;` at third line.

Comment: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: @memite7760 this is a different question now.

Comment: I have fixed that problem but didn't show latest payments and still shows latest orders!

Comment: @memite7760 make sure you copy my code. notice I have not used `Order::query()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the `payments` table first if you want to sort the orders by the latest payment:

```
$orders = Order::leftJoin('payments', function($join){
        $join->on('orders.ord_id', '=', 'payments.pay_ord_id')
            ->on('payments.pay_id', '=', \DB::raw("(SELECT pay_id from payments WHERE orders.ord_id = payments.pay_ord_id ORDER BY created_at DESC limit 1)"));
    })
    ->with([
        'payments' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
        }
    ])
    ->orderBy('payments.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('orders.created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```